# Can mosek write to opf format (via Pyomo)?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, mosek

We are formulating an optimization problem in Mosek (via its Pyomo interface).

We required to dump the problem in `opf` format.

To enable this, we activated the `iparam.opf_write_problem` [0] solver option, but failed (i.e. no `opf` file created).

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import mosek

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var([1,2], domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = 2*model.x[1] + 3*model.x[2])
model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = 3*model.x[1] + 4*model.x[2] >= 1)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory("mosek")
opt.solve(model, options={'iparam.opf_write_problem': 1})   # doesn't create opf file

# opt.solve(model, options={'iparam.opf_write_problem': mosek.onoffkey.on})  # fails too
```

Is this a bug in Mosek or Pyomo?

Reference:

[0] https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/toolbox/parameters.html#mosek.iparam.opf_write_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These opf parameters only dictate which parts of the data are supposed to be included the opf file when it is being written and which not.

To actually write a file from Pyomo follow the example in https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/faq/faq.html#pyomo, changing the file name to something.opf.